# Manually update Angular version

Tags: angular

I want to update Angular version from 8 to 9.

But I have some issues with automatic update, using `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`.

If I manually change dependencies in `package.json` of `@angular/core`, `@angular/common` etc, will it correctly update to version 9?

Comment: Yes (more characters needed to reply)

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend doing it manually as you miss the update schematics. Just add —force and it will ignore dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to follow the guide propose by the Angular Oficial Site:

https://update.angular.io/

There you can set what is your current version and how complex it's your application in order to define what changes and updates you have to do.